# How do I use BackboneFire to read data from Firebase but save changes to a REST API?

Tags: backbone.js, firebase

I'm trying to implement a Backbone.Firebase.Collection where the page updates in real-time based on a Firebase node, but when a user makes changes to a model, it saves the updated data to a backend REST API. I've tried overriding both the `sync` and `save` methods, but it still keeps trying to save back to firebase instead of the API. Here's my code for the save override.

```
app.Resource = Backbone.NestedModel.extend({
    save: function(attributes, options) {
        var modelID = "";
        if (this.attributes.id) {
            modelID = this.attributes.id + "/";
        }
        options = _.defaults((options || {}), {url: "/api/v2/resources/" + modelID});
        return Backbone.NestedModel.prototype.save.call(this, attributes, options);
    },
});
```

Comment: There is no code here using Backbone/Firebase in conjunction, which would be done with Backbone.Firebase.Collection or Backbone.Firebase.Model. This certainly doesn't reproduce any error like the one you've described.